# ¿Como Poner un datePicker en un Recycler view?

Tags: android

Este es el codigo que tengo para el adaptador del RecyclerView

```
public class AdaptadorProgramacion extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder>
    implements ItemClickListener {

private List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> ListaClienteRecuperaciones;
public Context contexto;


public AdaptadorProgramacion(Context contexto, List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> ClienteRecuperaciones) {

    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ListaClienteRecuperaciones = ClienteRecuperaciones;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView lblDocumento;
    public TextView lblNombre;
    public TextView lblDireccion;
    public TextView lblFecha;
    public CheckBox chck_Seleccionado;
    public ItemClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
        super(v);

        lblDocumento = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDocumento);
        lblNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblNombre);
        lblDireccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDireccion);
        chck_Seleccionado = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chck_Seleccionado);
        lblFecha = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblFecha);
        this.listener = listener;
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

    }
}

@Override
public AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_programacion, parent, false);
    return new AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder(vista, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.lblDocumento.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getDocumento());
    holder.lblNombre.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getNombres());
    holder.lblDireccion.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getDireccion());

    holder.lblFecha.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Aqui deberia ir el codigo que haga funcionar el DatePicker

                   Fecha fec=new Fecha();
                    fec.MostrarFecha();
                    if (fec.Resulado !=null)
                    {
                        holder.lblFecha.setText(fec.Resulado);
                    }
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListaClienteRecuperaciones.size();
}
```

}

Aqui la Clase Fecha

```
   public class Fecha  extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
  public String Resulado;

 public void MostrarFecha()
{
    FragmentManager Frag = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DialogFragment picker = new DateDialog();
    picker.show(Frag, "DatePicker");
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    actualizarFecha(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}

public String actualizarFecha(int ano, int mes, int dia) {
    // Setear en el textview la fecha

    mes += 1;
    String cdia, cmes;
    if (dia < 10) {
        cdia = "0" + String.valueOf(dia);
    } else {
        cdia = String.valueOf(dia);
    }
    if (mes < 10) {
        cmes = "0" + String.valueOf(mes);
    } else {
        cmes = String.valueOf(mes);
    }
    Resulado=ano + "-" + cmes + "-" + cdia;
   return Resulado;
}
```

}

Aqui la Clase DateDialog

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 public class DateDialog  extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Obtener fecha actual
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Retornar en nueva instancia del dialogo selector de fecha
    return new DatePickerDialog(
            getActivity(),
            (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),
            year,
            month + 1,
            day);
}
```

}

Clase DecoracionLineaDivisoria

```
    public class DecoracionLineaDivisoria extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private Drawable lineaDivisoria;

public DecoracionLineaDivisoria(Context context) {
    lineaDivisoria = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.linea_divisoria);
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        int bottom = top + lineaDivisoria.getIntrinsicHeight();

        lineaDivisoria.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        lineaDivisoria.draw(c);
    }
}
```

}

Activad donde Llamo al adaptador

```
  public class ActividadProgramacionRecuperaciones extends 
   AppCompatActivity {
   private static final String TAG = 
   ActividadProgramacionRecuperaciones.class.getSimpleName();
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
   private AdaptadorProgramacion adaptador;

   private static List<ClienteRecuperacionModel>ListaProgramados;
   public static void createInstance(Activity activity, 
    List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> pListaProgramados) {


    ListaProgramados = pListaProgramados;
    Intent intent = getLaunchIntent(activity);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
  public static Intent getLaunchIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActividadProgramacionRecuperaciones.class);
    return intent;
}


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_programacion_recuperaciones);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
   findViewById(R.id.rv_clienteProgramacion);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    showToolbar(getResources().getString(R.string.Programación), true);

  adaptador = new AdaptadorProgramacion(this, ListaProgramados);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(this));

}
private void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton) {

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
}
```

}

[image: Imagen]

Como se puede observar en la imagen al darle click en el textView de fecha
deberia mostrar el DatePicker en un DialogFragment.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Esto es lo que muestra el logCat:

--------- beginning of crash

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: pe.com.cmacica.credimovil, PID: 30278
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1560)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:696)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:662)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
                                                                               at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.Repositorio.Adaptadores.Recuperaciones.Fecha.MostrarFecha(Fecha.java:25)
                                                                               at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.Repositorio.Adaptadores.Recuperaciones.AdaptadorProgramacion$1.onClick(AdaptadorProgramacion.java:89)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

---

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: pe.com.cmacica.credimovil, PID: 31458
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.content.Context.getDrawable(int)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:30)
                                                       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:372)
                                                       at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.Utilitarios.DecoracionLineaDivisoria.(DecoracionLineaDivisoria.java:19)
                                                       at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.ViewModel.Recuperaciones.fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.ProcesarClientes(fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.java:424)
                                                       at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.ViewModel.Recuperaciones.fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.-wrap1(fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.java)
                                                       at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.ViewModel.Recuperaciones.fragmentoListaRecuperaciones$6.onResponse(fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.java:399)
                                                       at pe.com.cmacica.flujocredito.ViewModel.Recuperaciones.fragmentoListaRecuperaciones$6.onResponse(fragmentoListaRecuperaciones.java:396)
                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
                                                       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Hey Julio bienvenido!, el problema es que no se abre el DialogFragment? , Revisa el LogCat y agrega el mensaje de error.

Comment: Hola Jorge Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pe.com.cmacica.credimovil, PID: 19219 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.content.Context.getDrawable(int)' on a null object reference
 at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:30)at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:372)

Comment: Utiliza el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/95014/edit)  para agregar actualizaciones a tu respuesta y se más especifico. Donde creas el DialogFragment que no lo veo! en algún lugar estas usando getDrawable() .

Comment: Perfecto Jorge he puesto todo lo que estoy utilizando.

Comment: No lodro determinar cual sea el problema, en tu LogCat busca un mensaje que diga "Caused by"...agrega un poco más de info del LogCat por favor.

Comment: Listo se agrego todo lo que muestra el logCat. Cuando le doy Click al tetview de la fecha en el reclyclerView, ahi es donde se crashea la aplicación .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder mostrar el DatePicker en el RecyclerView
Creas un Variable del tipo Holder.
Cuando ingrese al Evento click del Textview Fecha, ahí se captura el Holder del Adaptador.
Espero les pueda servir la solución que me sirvió a mi.

```
public class AdaptadorProgramacion extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder>
    implements ItemClickListener {

private List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> ListaClienteRecuperaciones;
public Context contexto;
int Contador=0;
String date;
List<ClienteRecuperacionModel>ListaProgramados=new ArrayList<ClienteRecuperacionModel>();
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
private AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder HolderFecha;

public AdaptadorProgramacion(Context contexto, List<ClienteRecuperacionModel> ClienteRecuperaciones) {

    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.ListaClienteRecuperaciones = ClienteRecuperaciones;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView lblDocumento;
    public TextView lblNombre;
    public TextView lblDireccion;
    public TextView lblFecha;
    public CheckBox chck_Seleccionado;
    public TextView lblNumero;
    public ItemClickListener listener;

    public ViewHolder(View v, ItemClickListener listener) {
        super(v);

        lblDocumento = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDocumento);
        lblNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblNombre);
        lblDireccion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblDireccion);
        chck_Seleccionado = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chck_Seleccionado);
        lblFecha = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblFecha);
        lblNumero=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblNumero);
        this.listener = listener;
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

    }
}

@Override
public AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_programacion, parent, false);
    return new AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder(vista, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdaptadorProgramacion.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.lblDocumento.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getDocumento());
    holder.lblNombre.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getNombres());
    holder.lblDireccion.setText(ListaClienteRecuperaciones.get(position).getDireccion());

    holder.lblFecha.setOnClickListener((View view)-> {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                contexto,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                mDateSetListener,
                year,month,day);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
        HolderFecha=holder;
    });


    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            HolderFecha.lblFecha.setText(date);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ListaClienteRecuperaciones.size();
}
```

}